# Symfony 2 Choice Field Default Value

Tags: forms, symfony

I have this field in my form:

```
    ->add('taskOwner', null, array(
        'label' => $this-> translator ->trans( 'tasks.index.responsible' , array() , 'crm' )))
```

Symfony recognize it as Choice Type (it's have foreign key to another table, with users). Now i want to set the default value on the logged user. How I can do that ? I tried in my controller create new entity of my type, set taskOwner into it and then by SetData put in into form, like this:

```
    $entity = new Tasks();
    $tasksForm = $this->createForm(new TasksType($translator), $entity);

    $userId = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser()->getId();
    $user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('CloudAdmBundle:AdmUser')->find($userId);
    $task = new Tasks();
    $task->setTaskOwner($user);
    $tasksForm->setData($task);
```

To clear everything, definition of setter:

```
   public function setTaskOwner(\Cloud\AdmBundle\Entity\AdmUser $taskOwner = null)
    {
        $this->taskOwner = $taskOwner;

        return $this;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it before you create the form:

```
$userId = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser()->getId();
$user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('CloudAdmBundle:AdmUser')->find($userId);
$entity = new Tasks();
$entity->setTaskOwner($user);
$tasksForm = $this->createForm(new TasksType($translator), $entity);
```